# "finir en" or "finir par"

Tags: prépositions, verbes

"I would like to finish my presentation by asking you a question."

> Je voudrais finir ma présentation ___ une question.

Should it be *en vous posant* or *par vous poser* or something else? I think *finir par* is not correct here because it means "[to end up doing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/finir)", which is not the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to choose:

> Je voudrais finir ma présentation **en vous posant** une question.
>   Je voudrais finir ma présentation **par** une question.

Comment: What about in this example? "en appuyer sur le bouton" vs "par appuyer sur le bouton" vs "par le bouton"?

Comment: @AaronFranke you may use "Je voudrais finir ma présentation en appuyant sur le bouton", but "par appuyer" is not correct, you must use a noun, as "par l'appui sur le bouton rouge" maybe, where "appui" is not a verb but a noun.